LaTeX Warning: which document is concerned?
My log file is about 15,000 lines long, and identifying all the warnings is not easy, particularly those that look like:
LaTeX Warning: Reference `' on page 76 undefined on input line 282.

I have tons of .tex documents, and currently, my only way to find the needle in the haystack is to look at line 282 of each document:
find . -iname '*.tex' -exec perl -ne 'if($. == 282){print "File: $ARGV\n$_"}' {} \; | grep ref

It would obviously be easier if LaTeX could give me the name of the document. From other SO questions, I tried to add the following, but it doesn't help:
\usepackage{currfile}
\PackageWarning{Build error in File}{\currfilepath}

Also adding to the build command -file-line-error doesn't work for warnings:
latexmk --shell-escape -pdf -file-line-error -lualatex -cd build/index.tex

Is there a way to quickly identify the warnings, filter them, and identify the files concerned?
In addition, I tried to use texloganalyser, but as you can see the line information is useless because I don't have the matching file. It seems even log analyzer tools are dumb.
texloganalyser -h build/book/index.log
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 521--523
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 532--534
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 537--539
Overfull \hbox (10.79637pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 59--60
Overfull \hbox (113.784pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 68--69
Overfull \hbox (0.58896pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 81--82
Overfull \hbox (10.89139pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
Overfull \hbox (10.89139pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--3


just look in the log file for the nearest unclosed (./path/to/some/file.tex  and that is the file the line number references

@DavidCarlisle it is easy to say, but depending on the case the nearest \(\..*?\.tex is one thousand line above the warning.

\usepackage{currfile} \makeatletter \def\on@line{ on input line \the\inputlineno\space in \currfilepath}\makeatother?

why do you have a thousand warnings? but anyway it doesn't really matter perl or your editor should find it easily enough, often i just have the log open in the editor, type a ) after the message to simulate a file close and the matching ( where the file path is auto-highlighted. or add the filename to the message as Ulrike shows

@UlrikeFischer That change is great.  (Is there any reason not to change all of LaTeX to do that?)

@JimHefferon there shouldn't be a general dependency on currfile in LaTeX and keeping track of file names comes at a cost.  Also it doesn't always do what you want, e.g. if you use the primitive input. I generally prefer to use \RequirePackage{structuredlog} if there are many files.

@DavidCarlisle I don't have thousand warnings, perhaps around 50. I can write scripts to parse the log or even do what @UlrikeFischer suggests, but it is more like a general question. texlogfilter is quite nice, but it is an additional dependency

@nowox ok I rephrase my question, why do you have a thousand lines of log between the file open and the emty ref warning?

@DavidCarlisle Not sure what I am supposed to have. You can have a look: (https://gist.github.com/yves-chevallier/5253bba74a6ea627daf91acef9c32933)

hmm the graphics and minted messages are a bit chatty but having all those overfull boxes makes the log (and the output) worse but before worying about that, or worrying about the warning in the question, you need to fix all the missing character errors as they will be producing unusable output.

why does your index redefine \rmfamily and \sffamily and \ttfamily for every entry?

@UlrikeFischer It is probably minted that does that. I'll find a way to upload an artifact with the source.
